# Unable to install extensions: HTTP redirection error

Tags: extension, php

I'm unable to install CiviCRM extensions from CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM. On the CiviCRM extensions page I get the following error:

> WARNING: The downloader may be unable to download files which require
>   HTTP redirection. This may be a configuration issue with PHP's
>   open_basedir or safe_mode.

When I try to install an extension I get the following errors:
[image: CiviCRM error]

I've checked and:

The PHP setting open_basedir is not defined. 
The PHP setting safe_mode is set to off

What's going on?

I've got CiviCRM 4.5.5 installed with Wordpress 4.1.1

Comment: I have the same issue with one of the hosts that I use, but in my case they do use open_basedir and don't want to stop using it for security reasons. I simply work around it by manually installing the extensions I need either via SFTP or using wget on the command line when logged in via ssh.

Answer (score 4):

Try again now. I think Tim has resolved an issue that arose with the need for a new intermediate certificate for the SSL certificate replaced on C.o earlier this week: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16191. Please comment on the issue if your error has been resolved.

Comment: This is not fixed for me. I've checked on Chrome and Firefox and get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and resolved by bumping my PHP version from 5.3.29 to 5.4.13 -- can you check if this corrects the issue for you?

Answer (score 1):

This is not fixed for me trying to add new extension on 4.6.8.

Bug reported: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17263

[image]