# Can't Download Extensions

Tags: extension

I attempted to enable the Stripe payment processor in CiviCRM 4.6.4 by going to Administer > Administration Console > Manage Extensions > Add New. From there I click the Download link next to Stripe. After doing so I get the following error message:

"Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Unknown extension: com.drastikbydesign.stripe"

This message appears when attempting to download other extensions as well.

My CiviCRM Extensions Directory is: /home/sitename/www/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/
My Extension Resource URL is:
http://sitename.org/home/sitename/www/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/

As a possible lead, I get the following error message when entering the Extensions screen: "WARNING: The downloader may be unable to download files which require HTTP redirection. This may be a configuration issue with PHP's open_basedir or safe_mode." If this error message is related, I'm still not sure how to proceed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your Extension Resource URL path as below and give a try 
http://sitename.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/upload/

I guess this should work - please let me know the status thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response Ramesh. However, the error message remains.

Comment: Please read the following link http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34181.0  also http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/152/unable-to-install-extensions-http-redirection-error. - If your getting the error again please try installing the extension manually

Comment: I did eventually have to download the extension manually. For anyone reading this in the future, this meant downloading the ZIP file, unzip it into my extensions directory on the web server (Using WinSCP), then refreshing the administrator's extensions interface with CiviCRM.  Thanks, Ramesh, for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and resolved by bumping my PHP version from 5.3.29 to 5.4.13 -- can you check if this corrects the issue for you?